# Number masking & nls_parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

So i have a query:

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(COLUMN1*(COLUMN3-COLUMN2)),2) FROM .... WHERE ....
```

**EDIT:** ROUND to 2 decimals.

It returns this format - example:

```
  5.25
231.12
   .92
```

(expected output: `# ##0,00`):

```
  5,25
231,12
  0,92
```

So, how can i mask this correctly ?

```
SELECT ROUND(
to_number(SUM(COLUMN1*(COLUMN3-COLUMN2)),'[FORMAT_MASK]', '[NLS_PARAM=]')
,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR` specifying  a decimal character `D` in the format model appropriately

When your session's `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is `,.`   ( "*decimal_character group_separator*" )  by default or you've set it manually using

```
alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.'; 

select to_char(231.12, '99999D99')  from dual;
```

displays

```
231,12
```

You may alter the behaviour by assigning `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` as the 3rd argument

```
select to_char(231.12, '99999D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')  from dual;

231,12
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a275104eb16323e84e9002efcf70711)

Comment: I added a `0` into the format_mask -> `'99990D99'` because of the value `0,92`. It's working fine. Thanks man!