# Oracle SQL Commas format?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to have my numbers have commas

i.e.

4333 ---> 4,333

I came up with this

```
TO_CHAR(COUNT(*),'$9,999.99') AS TOTAL_APPS
```

basically Im counting everything in the db and want the commas present, this is already in a select statement and according to oracle docs that is the structure for commas, what is the issue?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number masking & nls\_parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53722579/number-masking-nls-parameter)

Comment: Can you provide code that you're running, what it returns, and what you expect it to return?  I'm not sure what you're asking here.  If you're trying to display the value with commas, TO_CHAR(number, format) should be the correct function, and the format models are documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

Answer (score 1):

So, what's wrong with *what you came up with*? Doesn't it do what you wanted?

Though, it looks like you found it somewhere on the Internet and applied to your situation because

This is what you have:

```
4333
```

This is what you want:

```
4,333
```

This is what you have (with `'$9,999.99'` format mask), i.e. there's a dollar sign as well as decimals which you - apparently - don't want:

```
SQL> select to_char(4333, '$9,999.99') result from dual;

RESULT
----------
 $4,333.00
```

---

If you change the format mask to this:

```
SQL> select to_char(4333, '9G999', 'nls_numeric_characters = .,') result from dual;

RESULT
------
 4,333
```

you might get what you wanted.

Why did I use it like this? `G` is the "thousands" separator. It can be different in different databases; someone uses a comma, someone else uses a dot, etc. `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` says which character is actually being used for the `G` mark, so it could have been e.g.

```
SQL> select to_char(4333, '9G999', 'nls_numeric_characters = ^=') result from dual;

RESULT
------
 4=333
```

Comment: HI thank you so much for answering that clears it up! Does this tochar method change the data type? because when i try to insert it it says invalid numbers since the column data type is number

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach that will only work in SQL*Plus is to use SQL*Plus formatting.

In this example, a simple query return a large number. With no formatting we just get the plain number back.

```
SQL> select 373746764  from dual;

 373746764
----------
 373746764
```

Let's give it an alias, still no formatting:

```
SQL> select 373746764 tn from dual;

        TN
----------
 373746764
```

Now let's use teh `COL` formatting command in SQL*PLUS:

```
SQL> col tn form '999,999,990.00'

SQL> select 373746764 tn from dual;

             TN
---------------
 373,746,764.00
```

So,. in your case, you could create a script that has all these `COL column_alias` commands which you can call and ensure your scripts have appropriate column aliases to match.

for example a script called `formating.sql`:

```
COL total_apps form '999,999,990'
COL total_cost form '999,999,990.00'
```

Then you report.sql scriopt can have:

```
@formatting.sql

SELECT COUNT(*) TOTAL_APPS FROM the_table;
```

I think this will work with SQL Developer as well, but as I said this approach is for SQL*Plus.

For more widespread results then TO_CHAR on each query is the way to go.